# Telethon log in causes termination of other sessions

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I was writing an app to scrape all the channel images. I didn't finish it, but here is what I have now:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest

import config

with TelegramClient(config.username, config.api_id, config.api_hash).start(phone=config.phone,
                                                                           password=config.password) as client:
    async def main():
        url = input("Input channel link: ")
        channel = await client.get_entity(url)
        messages = []
        offset_msg = 0
        limit_msg = 100
        while True:
            history = await client(GetHistoryRequest(
                peer=channel,
                offset_id=offset_msg,
                offset_date=None, add_offset=0,
                limit=limit_msg, max_id=0, min_id=0,
                hash=0))
            for message in history.messages:
                print(message)
            break


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with client:
            client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

After the code finishes, if I try to enter any telegram app where I have an active session, I get kicked out of it. On the third try I wasn't even able to log in using my phone, instead I was receieving a popup "AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED"; I was able to login after I recovered my password via gmail.

Why is it happening? I am kind of scared of experimenting any more.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76009793/4759433.